# What options will make gpg ask for passphrase (and then do nothing with it)?

Tags: gnupg

I was reading `gpg`'s man page trying to make it ask for the passphrase and just that. Could not find any way... Do you have a solution?

PS for those who need to ask *what for?*: I'm writing a script where I want gpg to ask and check the passphrase **before** initiating a series of remote connections and decryptions of remote files. I don't want gpg to prompt me in the middle of a file transfer.

Answer (score 2):

This will only work when using GnuPG together with `gpg-agent`, a daemon taking care of the passphrase and in newer GnuPG releases cryptographic operations.

There is a tool `gpg-preset-passphrase` included in the GnuPG distribution, in Debian it is located in `/usr/lib/gnupg2/gpg-preset-passphrase` (probably not contained in your `$PATH` variable). It allows to cache the passphrase in `gpg-agent` to perform other operations using GnuPG afterwards.

A summary of options available:

```
$ /usr/lib/gnupg2/gpg-preset-passphrase  --help
gpg-preset-passphrase (GnuPG) 2.1.4
Copyright (C) 2015 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>
This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.

Syntax: gpg-preset-passphrase [options] KEYGRIP
Password cache maintenance

Options:

 -v, --verbose       verbose
 -P, --passphrase STRING   
                     use passphrase STRING
 -c, --preset        preset passphrase
 -f, --forget        forget passphrase

Please report bugs to <http://bugs.gnupg.org>.
```

To store a passphrase, use `/usr/lib/gnupg2/gpg-preset-passphrase -c DEADBEEF` for the OpenPGP key `DEADBEEF`. `gpg-agent` must already be running and configured.